# assembly language, strange loop

Tags: assembly

I'm struggling to understand what this code does

```
ldi r20, 80
loop: asr r20
     brsh loop
      nop
```

What is this code doing and how many clock cycles does this code take to execute?

Comment: You haven't told us what CPU this is for.

Comment: its for ave micro controller.

Comment: @user3603183 Do you mean AVR? I understand typos happen, but please try to be precise when asking for technical help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Atmel AVR assembly code.  In a loop that continues until the carry bit of the status register is set, it shifts hexadecimal `80` arithmetically right by one position so that `r20` takes the successive values of `80`, then `c0`, then `e0`, then `f0`, `f8`, `fc`, `fe`, `ff`.  Until now, the low bit has been `0`, and this value has been shifted into the carry bit of the status register. But on the next shift, the low bit of `ff` is shifted, which is a `1`.  This causes the loop to exit.

See http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_ASR.html on the ASR instruction.

The net effect is to cause a small delay.

Answer (score 0):

For clock cycles:

- ldi = 1,
- asr = 1,
- brsh = Documented at 1/2 I think 1 for false condition and 2 for true.
- nop = 1

Gene seems to be spot on in his answer so if my count is correct a total of 17 (don't bet any money on it).

source for the clock cycles was:
http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/COMMANDS.html#Functions